# Why does it take so much longer to run a mutate function using c_across(all_of()) (from tidyverse/dplyr) than !!!syms(...), in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am running a function in `mutate` that takes the row-wise means of a predefined list of column names (in a string vector).

For example, suppose we have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=21:30) 
A <- c("x", "y")
```

The way to do this without `c_across`/`all_of` would be:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>%
    mutate(M = sum(!!!syms(A)))
```

However, using `c_across`/`all_of`, we can write:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>%
    mutate(M = sum(c_across(all_of(A))))
```

Both of these are functionally equivalent, however on my real data (which have thousands of observations), the latter is very slow (more than 10 fold slower than the base R solution).

I like the `c_across`/`all_of` solution as it looks nicer than `!!!syms`, however it is not feasible to use this with my data as it is so slow.  Why is it so much slower?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on why it's so much slower, but if you want a solution that seems easier to read and is still fast, I'd recommend: `df %>% mutate(M = rowSums(across(all_of(A))))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, you have super high overhead when calling `c_across` + `all_of`, especially running by rows. That fact is that, you were running in a `rowwise()` manner, and you had to call `c_across` + `all_of` **over and over again**.

---

## Reasons of Slowness

From the source codes of `c_across` and `all_of` (see the attached codes) we can see that we have many intermediate steps before obtaining the desired columns listed in `A`, which is much **computational heavier** than directly evaluate the symbols `syms(A)`. However, you should be aware that `syms` is not sufficiently efficient either, since it is equivalent to `map(x, sym)` where using `map` to `sym` is not as straightforward as picking the columns directly (the same reason, many intermediate steps in `syms` and you need run `!!!` afterwards, see the source codes of `syms` and `sym`).

---

## Tips for Speed Improvement

A more straightforward and efficient approach is to "vectorize" your operations, rather than execute it "row-wisely". More specifically, you can select columns in `A` at the beginning, e.g., `df[A]` (one-shot solution such that you don't need to repeat doing the same thing over all rows), and than run `rowSums` for your objective. *This approach has been highlighted in [@Gki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455749/12158757)*.

---

- `c_across` + `all_of` source code

```
> c_across
function (cols)
{
    mask <- peek_mask()
    cols <- enquo(cols)
    if (quo_is_missing(cols)) {
        c_across_missing_cols_deprecate_warn()
        cols <- quo_set_expr(cols, expr(everything()))
    }
    vars <- c_across_setup(!!cols, mask = mask)
    cols <- mask$current_cols(vars)
    vec_c(!!!cols, .name_spec = zap())
}
<bytecode: 0x0000016758a08778>
<environment: namespace:dplyr>

> all_of
function (x)
{
    if (!has_vars()) {
        lifecycle::deprecate_soft("1.2.0", I("Using `all_of()` outside of a selecting function"),
            details = paste("See details at", peek_vars_link()))
        return(x)
    }
    vars <- peek_vars(fn = "all_of")
    as_indices_impl(x, vars = vars, strict = TRUE)
}
<bytecode: 0x00000167585374c0>
<environment: namespace:tidyselect>
```

- `syms` + `sym` source code

```
> syms
function (x)
{
    map(x, sym)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000016758740e70>
<environment: namespace:rlang>

> sym
function (x)
{
    if (is_symbol(x)) {
        return(x)
    }
    if (identical(x, "")) {
        return(missing_arg())
    }
    if (!is_string(x)) {
        abort_coercion(x, "a symbol")
    }
    .Call(ffi_symbol, x)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000016758747ed0>
<environment: namespace:rlang>
```

Answer (score 3):

The variant with `!!!syms(A)` is calling `sum` with `x` and `y`.
The variant with `c_across(all_of(A))` is calling `sum`, which is calling `c_across`, which is calling `all_of` with `A` what obviously needs time.

```
lobstr::ast( df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(M = sum(!!!syms(A))) )
#█─`%>%` 
#├─█─`%>%` 
#│ ├─df 
#│ └─█─rowwise 
#└─█─mutate 
#  └─M = █─sum 
#        ├─x 
#        └─y 

lobstr::ast( df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(M = sum(c_across(all_of(A)))) )
#█─`%>%` 
#├─█─`%>%` 
#│ ├─df 
#│ └─█─rowwise 
#└─█─mutate 
#  └─M = █─sum 
#        └─█─c_across 
#          └─█─all_of 
#            └─A
```

---

Just in case you want a base way:

```
cbind(df, M = rowSums(df[A]))
```

Benchmark

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=21:30) 
A <- c("x", "y")

bench::mark(check = FALSE,
         c_across = {df %>% rowwise() %>%
                mutate(M = sum(c_across(all_of(A))))},
         syms = {df %>% rowwise() %>%
                mutate(M = sum(!!!syms(A)))},
         across = df %>% mutate(M = rowSums(across(all_of(A)))), # @nrennie
         base = cbind(df, M = rowSums(df[A])) )

#  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 c_across    12.64ms  12.82ms      77.1  314.84KB     22.0    28     8
#2 syms         3.22ms   3.64ms     254.     4.62KB     15.5   115     7
#3 across       1.81ms   2.01ms     487.   125.21KB     17.3   225     8
#4 base       180.52µs 196.49µs    4849.         0B     16.8  2307     8
```

Comment: nice visualization and benchmarking! +1!